# Transposing and Where Criteria

Tags: where-clause, teradata, transpose

I was wondering if there is a more efficient of writing the code below (which does not work). I am trying to transpose a data set, but only want values where Dogs and Cats are greater than 1. As in a group has both cat and dogs.

The code below does not work, but is my attempt to pull base on the above statement. Please feel free to modify the codes below and/or provide better codes. Thanks in advance!

```
    select 
    ,group_id
    ,sum(case when product = '18' then 1 else 0 end) as "Dogs"
    ,sum(case when product = '20' then 1 else 0 end) as "Cats"

    from risk_bl

    where dogs > 1 and cats > 1

    group by 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `HAVING` clause:

```
select 
,group_id
,sum(case when product = '18' then 1 else 0 end) as "Dogs"
,sum(case when product = '20' then 1 else 0 end) as "Cats"

from risk_bl
group by 1
having sum(case when product = '18' then 1 else 0 end) > 1 
and sum(case when product = '20' then 1 else 0 end)> 1
```

As dnoeth pointed out, Teradata allows you to use aliases in your having clause (among other things) so your having clause could also read:

```
 having dogs > 1 and cats > 1
```

The having clause applies after grouping and aggregation, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Teradata allows using an aliased column name, which simplifies the query to: `having dogs > 1 and cats > 1`

Comment: I know. I kind of flip back and forth on that, because most other RDBMSs don't support that.

Comment: It breaks all rules of RDBMSes, but it's just nice to have :-)